# Length of an array is not defined when called in Jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I get this error: [length not defined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVNGO.png) when running this code in Jade:

```
each time in appointment.location.openingTimes
        p
          | #{time.days}: 
          if time.closed
            span.pull-right.badge-default closed
          else
            span.pull-right.badge-default #{time.opening} - #{time.closing}
```

It is referencing this array:

```
appointment: {
        reason: 'Johnny to Busby3',
        location: [{
            name: 'Buga Buga Hospital',
            phoneNumber: '(719) 589-1011',
            address: {
                street: '125 High Street',
                region: 'Buga Buga, HI 85555',
            },
            distance: '100m',
            coords: {
                lat: 51.455041,
                lng: -0.9690884
            },
            openingTimes: [{
                days: 'Monday - Friday',
                opening: '7:00 am',
                closing: '7:00 pm',
                closed: false
            }, {
                days: 'Saturday',
                opening: '8:00 am',
                closing: '5:00 pm',
                closed: false
            }, {
                days: 'Sunday',
                closed: true
            }],
        }],
```

I am thinking there is some naming issues going on but I cannot find them.

Comment: location is an array, so you can't access openingTimes with a dot accessor (location is an array of objects that have the openingTimes property) so you'd need two loops or restructure your data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy. `location` is **an array** that has an object inside.

> use `appointment.location[0].openingTimes`

Answer (score 0):

`appointment.location` is also an array.

To reach the object within that, which has the `openingTimes`, you'll have to access an index:

```
each time in appointment.location[0].openingTimes
    # ...
```

You can also iterate over `appointment.location` as well as `openingTimes`:

```
each location in appointment.location
    each time in location.openingTimes
        # ...
```

Comment: Excellent.  Giving this a try!